# Merge Sort. Error-- Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to String

Tags: java, file-io, mergesort, type-mismatch

The program below uses merge sort to arrange the first 10,000 words in a file. I followed the pseudocode of Thomas Cormen in his Introduction to Algorithms, Second Ed.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SortingAnalysis {

    public static void merge(String[] A, int p, int q, int r) {
        int n1 = q-p+1;
        int n2 = r-q;
        double infinity = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        int i, j;
        String[] L = null;
        String[] R = null;
        for (i=1; i<=n1; i++) {
            L[i] = A[(int) (p+i-1)];
        }
        for (j=1; j<=n2; j++) {
            R[j] = A[(int) (q+j)];
        }
        L[n1+1] = infinity; //type mismatch: cant convert from double to string
        R[n2+1] = infinity; //same as above
        i=1;
        j=1;
        for (int k=(int) p; k<=r; k++) {
            int comparison = L[i].compareTo(R[j]);
            if (comparison<=0) {
                A[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                A[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void mergeSort(String[] A, int p, int r) {
        if (p<r) {
            int q = (int) Math.floor((p+r)/2); //I typecasted q here so I can still pass the variables
            mergeSort(A, p, q);
            mergeSort(A, q+1, r);
            merge(A, p, q, r);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NO_OF_WORDS = 10000;
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            String[] words = new String[NO_OF_WORDS];

            int i = 0;
            while(file.hasNext() && i < NO_OF_WORDS) {
                words[i] = file.next();
                i++;
            }
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mergeSort(words, 0, words.length-1);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Sorted Words: ");
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(words[j]);
            }   
            System.out.print("Running time of insertion sort: " + (end - start) + "ms");

        }
        catch(SecurityException securityException) {
            System.err.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

There is an error displayed in the console saying 

 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to String
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to String`

```
at SortingAnalysis.merge ... mergeSort and main </code>
```

I think it is because of the Math.floor method which is supposed to be a double but I did typecast it into int so there will be no problem when passing the parameters.
Also, I think there was an error in assigning a String to infinity. But I'm just following Cormen's pseudocode.  It seems right because I "debugged" the code by hand by myself. However, when I put it into the code, it's not working. Where can I go wrong? I need your help, folks. I'm new in Java and I'm still in the buffering process. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

> I think it is because of the Math.floor method which is supposed to be a double but I did typecast it into int so there will be no problem when passing the parameters.

No, it's simpler than that. You're trying to assign a *double* value into a *string* array. You simply can't do that.

I strongly suspect you should change your whole code to use `double[]` instead of `String[]`. Note that even when it's compiling (and you shouldn't try to *run* it until you've really fixed all the compilation errors) you'll have a problem due to this:

```
String[] L = null;
String[] R = null;
for (i=1; i<=n1; i++) {
    L[i] = A[(int) (p+i-1)];
}
```

That's clearly going to throw a `NullPointerException`. You're not initializing the array variables to refer to array objects. You want something like:

```
double[] L = new double[n1 + 1];
double[] R = new double[n1 + 1];
for (i=1; i<=n1; i++) {
    L[i] = A[(int) (p+i-1)];
}
```

It's odd to use arrays in a 1-based way, by the by... it would be *much* more idiomatic to do something like:

```
double[] L = new double[n1];
double[] R = new double[n1];
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    L[i] = A[p + i];
}
```

It feels like you're struggling because you're trying to learn two things here:

- How MergeSort works
- How Java works

I would concentrate on understanding the Java language *first* - at that point you'll be in a much better position to convert pseudocode into real code.

Comment: Thank you, Jon! Being a newbie, I'm enlightened, thank you! Maybe I'll do some major modifications in my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Casting to an `(int)` will do a floor anyway.

```
  L[n1+1] = infinity; //type mismatch: cant convert from double to string
```

This is an error because you can't cast a a `double` to a `String` Even if you converted it with `toString()` it would not be correct because you would just get "NaN" which is not the maixmum String value which it appears to be your goal.

You can code this without adding a dummy "infinity" value and I suggest you do that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Peter! I appreciate it! Maybe I'll just do some modifications in my code.